# Woocommerce Product Page Breadcrumb-title edit

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmXBR.png)
I want to replace the top Store page name on the wordpress product page with the product name, can anyone help?

example:
[i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt5kM.png)
How can I do? There is no such setting in the properties of the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what theme you are using or how the Shop title is being generated, try adding this code to your functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'woo_shop_page_title');
function woo_shop_page_title( $page_title ) {
    if( 'Shop' == $page_title) {
        return the_title();
    }
 }
```

This code replaces the page title Shop with the title of the product (post).

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function woo_shop_page_title() in C:\wamp64\www\artyge\wp-content\themes\retbo\inc\template-helper.php:1570

I'm looking from phpstorm giving this error. and the page title does not change unfortunately :/ :(

Comment: Check that woo_shop_page_title is spelled the same in both the filter and the function.